# I am trying to wait for data from firebase before running last line in a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo

I'm trying to get longitude and latitude from firebase firestore and then use the data to calculate distance but the function doing the calculations runs before the data has been retrieved from firebase,please help I am new to react native and JavaScript.

```
function fetchProducts() {
const myProduct = [];
db.collection("item")
  .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
      const { createdAt, category, image, values, latitude, longitude } =
        doc.data();

      myProduct.push({
        createdAt,
        id: doc.id,
        latitude,
        longitude,
        category,
        image,
        values,
      });
    });
    setNewProduct(myProduct);
    myData();
  });
```

}

```
const myData = () => {
myNewProduct = newProduct;
GetCurrentLocation().then(() => {
  myNewProduct.forEach((element) => {
    mydistance = calcDistance(
      element.latitude,
      element.longitude,
      newLatitude,
      newLongitude
    );
    element.distance = mydistance;
  });

  myNewProduct.sort((a, b) => a.distance - b.distance);
  setProduct(myNewProduct);
});
```

};

Comment: The problem is that `myNewProduct = newProduct;` does *not* create a copy. The reference is maintained, so React cannot *react* to the fact that you call `setProduct(myNewProduct);` in the end because it's still the same reference. Also note that state changes are not immediate, so running myData() right after `setNewProduct(myProduct);` will not work as expected; myData will use the old value.

Comment: The solution is to use the useEffect hook to react to the state change of `newProduct` to do the coordinate calculation. And you can use .map() to create a changed copy of the current state, then pass the result to the setter function.